# Vector filling array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
v1 = np.zeros(20) 
v2 = np.zeros(20)

data = [ list of length 20]

for i, ele in enumerate(data):
      if ele.type != 'foo'
           v1[i] = 1
           v2[i] = 20
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do this in "vector" world??

Comment: What type of object is `ele`? That is, what's in `data`?

Comment: data contains a list of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way is to use [boolean index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
v1 = np.zeros(20) 
v2 = np.zeros(20)
is_foo = np.asarray([ele.type == "foo" for ele in data])
v1[~is_foo] = 1
v2[~is_foo] = 20
```

or, without "allocating" the arrays ahead of time:

```
is_foo = np.asarray([ele.type == "foo" for ele in data])
v1 = np.where(~is_foo, 1, 0)
v2 = np.where(~is_foo, 20, 0)
```